# Sending Duplicate Name Values in a PHP Form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, key-value

I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong way, so I'm here to ask.

I have a form that's sending out multiple HTML form `$_POST` keys (`name` attribute) and values (`value` attribute).

The looks HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="Quantity">
```

I have some jQuery multiplying price by quantity and submitting them to the form.

[Here is a link to a pen demonstrating the form](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/XKdVEG).

That part works fine. Then on form submit, I'm just serializing all the data and sending it through with `serialize()`. Simplified example...

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

  var formValues = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send.php',
    data: formValues
  });
});
```

And the PHP looks like this (simplified!)

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $message .=  $key.': '.$value. "\n";
}
```

So, everything works properly - the JavaScript adds up all the quantities and sends it to the PHP. My only issue is you can't have multiple `name` attributes sending out, so I have to change them for each input.

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="Quantity1">
<input type="text" value="0" name="Quantity2">
```

So, I guess my question is how to change the name attribute to something more readable in an e-mail.

In other words, the e-mail sends out as:

- **Product 1**
- Quantity1: 10
- **Product 2**
- Quantity2: 12

and I want it to just be...

- **Product 1**
- Quantity: 10
- **Product 2**
- Quantity: 12

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What do you actually require? Do you need a naming convention for quantity ?

Comment: I don't know how you would access them in JS but to get an array in PHP use `name="Quantity[]"`. Then you can loop the `$_POST['Quantity']` array.

Comment: In the e-mail, it send outs as "Quantity1: x, Quantity2: y`. I want it to just say "Quantity" no matter what.

Comment: @TaniaRascia
So how would this work ?
Quantity : x
Quantity : x?

Comment: Have you tried with `name="Quantity[]"`? This should send 1 unique _POST key and an array as its value. In the PHP you should check if `gettype($value)=='array'` or simply `$key=='Quantity'`and do another loop on that array.

Comment: @Akshay I have updated my post.

Comment: @TaniaRascia
I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all your inputs you can do `<input type="text" value="0" name="quantity[]">` and in your php

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $quantity){
 .... your stuff here
}
```

Seems like your products and quantities are in order and the same length i.e for every product there is only one quantity field. If that's true you can iterate through both in one loop.

```
$quantities = $_POST['quantity'];  // array of quantities

$products = $_POST['products'];  // array of products

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['quantity']); $i++){

     $quantity = $quantities[$i]; 
     $product = $products[$i]; 


 .... do more stuff here 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I suppose my issue is now that I have to make multiple foreach loops - `foreach($_POST['product'] as $product)`, `foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $quantity)` so it lists all the products THEN all the quantities, instead of product, quantity, product, quantity.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Just a note, the second `i++` caused the e-mail to send every OTHER input! So might want to take that out of the answer for any future googlers.

Comment: oops.. Don't know how that got in there.

Answer (score 1):

Ah this is simple, you can use a namemd array for this.

Something like this :-

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="quantity[]">
```

Now in your php, you can access the values in this way.

```
if(is_array($_POST['quantity']))
{
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $quantity)
{
//access the quantity.
//so the first time the loop runs, the quantity is for product 1
//second time -> Product 2
//and so on 
}
}
```